# discord.js - Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been making a discord bot and i don't know what the current problem is, please help.

```js
    module.exports = {
    name: "blah",
    category: "blahblah",
    description: "blahblah",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        let numMessages = args[0];
        let fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: numMessages});
        console.log(arr = fetched.array());
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
             const RichEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('blahblah')
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
        .addField('blahblah', message.author.tag)
        .addField('blahblah', message.content)
            .client.channels.cache.get("692783192574263364").send(RichEmbed);
        }
        message.channels.bulkDelete(args[0]);   
    }
```

It says me the next line:

```
(node:7736) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Object.run C:\PathToMyBotFolder\ThisScript:17:20)`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I took the liberty of editing your post as part of SO community service, so it is more concise and can help others better. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61105476/revisions - maybe this gives you some hints how to improve formatting and conciseness going forward on SO.

Comment: Regarding your initial problem: Did you note the end of the error message reading `:17:20)`? That is a hint from the runtime that it fell over at line number 17, character number 20. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because of a typo in your code, you wrote `.client` instead of `client`

Replace `.client.channels.cache.get("692783192574263364").send(RichEmbed);` with `client.channels.cache.get("692783192574263364").send(RichEmbed);`

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but it does not the function i wanted, anyway, this is an another question now, thanks again!